# How can I periodically transfer data from my local Oracle-XE database to a remote Oracle 11g?

Tags: database, oracle-database

Here's my use case:

In order to speed things up in my real time application, I came up with the idea of using Oracle-XE as a local cache database for faster access & then somehow transfer (preferably in bulk mode) the data from this local db to the remote database for later access. This transferring of data will be done periodically, say once in 24 hours.

Is there any already built tool/library that does this kind of job (preferably open-source)?